# Getting parent starting from src attributte

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, src, attr

i need to know if there's a way of getting parent starting with src attributte of img tag . I have something like : 6 draggable objects and 6 dropspots. At every drop i store in a variable src attribute of image i change. With this src i need to find its parrent and set .css("visibility", "visible"). My question : Is there a way to get parent of an img tag starting with its src attribute?

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/FncKS/

Code:

```
drop: function( event, ui )
            {
var dropTarget = event.target.id; 
var getSrcChanged = $("#" + dropTarget).children('img').attr("src");
console.log(getSrcChanged);
}
```

Where console return : `../images/map6.svg` (for example)

With this src attributte i would like to make one of draggable objects (the one with same src attributte) visible useing:

```
    var visible = $(dragObjects).children("img").src(getSrcChanged);
    $(visible).css("visibility", "visible");
```

But unfortunately it doesnt work :(

dragObjects its an array : 6 x `div.children("img").`

Some HTML:

```
<div class="random drag" id="draggable0">
     <img class="svgSize" src="images/map1.svg" draggable="false" />  
</div>

<div class="random drag" id="draggable1">
     <img class="svgSize" src="images/map2.svg" draggable="false" /> 
</div>

...

<div class="random drag" id="draggable5">
     <img class="svgSize" src="images/map6.svg" draggable="false" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @VedantTerkar Fiddle in edit! All js code inside to see what i have done. thanks :)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to do anything but show 12 broken images.

Comment: To make it work doesnt show anything. I just added a fiddle for you all to see the whole js code. The only thing i miss ,as i said, is written in js fiddle js code with comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your scenario very confusing, but it sounds like this is what you want to do:

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var dropTarget = event.target.id,
        getSrcChanged = $("#" + dropTarget).children('img').attr("src"),
        matchingDraggable =  $(dragObjects).find("img[src='"+ getSrcChanged +"'");
    matchingDraggable.css("visibility", "visible");
    console.log(getSrcChanged);
}
```

Could you give that a try?

Comment: I just did it my way too like that :

var getSrcChanged = $("#" + dropTarget).children('img').prop("src");
                    
var visible = getSrcChanged.charAt(getSrcChanged.length-5);
$(dragObjects[visible]).css("visibility", "visible");

But ur answer is good too! exactly what i was looking for :)